# Extending Python with C on Windows - ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-extensions

So, I'm interested in communicating between a C program and a Python program so that I can neatly send tasks and data between the two.

I figured I'd go ahead and start with [this guide](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_further_extensions.htm). In this guide I have a C file with contents outlined in the example in the link right above the "Building and Installing Extensions" title and the python code from right under it. After I run the `python setup.py install` command I try to import the created module through

```
>>>import helloworld                                                                                                   
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

So I suppose the issue is that the extension is 32-bit while my Python installation is 64-bit? The python I'm using is

```
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

All help appreciated!

Comment: I think you have answered your own question.  Compile your DLL as 64-bit.